# Could not load file or assembly 'clrcompression, xamarin forms UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

During OnLaunched at Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e); the app throws
System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not load file or assembly 'clrcompression,

I have the following dependencies

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.2",
"Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
"System.Collections.Immutable": "1.2.0",
"Xamarin.Forms": "2.3.1.114"
```

All the xamarin sample apps for uwp are running without a problem.

UPDATE: The exception is now gone, reason unknown. The only known difference is that i added and then removed xlabs dependencies. 
I think this triggered a rebuild of a broken dependency graph?!

It would still be nice to know how to debug this dependency graph issues.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue. On dependencies are Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v5.2.2" and Xamarin.Forms v2.3.2.127. I've tried to down grade Microsoft.NETCore to 5.1 to no effect. I also tried adding and then removing xlabs.core. That had no effect either. Did you make any other observations? I've not been able to find much in this issue.

Comment: I did not solve this problem but for me it works when I ignore this exception and continue execution.

Comment: I'm getting this error as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens if you have all of the 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions' enabled in your Exception Settings.

Often at program load (in many .NET frameworks), there will be exceptions which are fired which are completely harmless and correctly handled.

If this exception is bothering you then simply deselect 'Break when this exception is thrown' and hit Continue.

[image]