# Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e) FileNotFoundExeception in Onlaunched

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

My Android Application works fine but when I launch my UWP application it crashes in the OnLaunched of my App.xaml.cs at the line of Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e)

This is the error I'm getting:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'clrcompression, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.'

It completely makes my app crash, only thing I can see is my Splashscreen.

In IOS got a similar issue. It also show an error of FileNotFoundexception but it doesn't break and I can go past it. It show the error in my Main.cs at the line of UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");

Comment: in the UWP project any images that you are using need to be in the root of the project (which I find weird and messy, but it's true.), otherwise it won't find them and you'll get that lovely exception.

Comment: Is it possible that i'm just missing an image in my folder? I've used a folder in my root to put my images in, and than I have method to check if it's uwp to add the folder name to the path. I've done this before and haven't had any issue with it yet.

Comment: entirely possible yep. to get it so early in the apps life cycle suggests it could be a tab bar image (if you're using one). but yeah I'd definately double check your UWP project to see if you're missing one.

Comment: I've just looked every image and can't seem to find the missing one :/, do you have any idea where I could possible find the missing image ( like where an error show up?)

Comment: I've just done a little research around the above, are you using XLabs at all?

Comment: I used to have Xlabs but I threw it away because I was getting errors in Android with it. Is it possible that a piece of the installation remained on uwp?

Comment: yeah i just found someone else getting the same error, and they said that in the end it was caused by an XLab assembly reference messing up. So definately worth checking to see theres none referenced in your UWP project.

Comment: Ima delete the bin/obj and the .vs folder and see if that fixes my issue

Comment: Thanks! that works! If u want u can post it as answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments of the original post, and for anyone else that stumbles accross this thread with the same exception, in most instances the cause would appear to be related to Xlabs assemblies either not loading correctly, or having not been removed completely. This appears to have been an issue for at least the last half a year (past example of similar situation can be found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133760/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-clrcompression-xamarin-forms-uwp)).

The solution in this instance if you removed the xlab references but still get the error, is to delete the obj/bin/.VS folders from your project folder. Then for a UWP project, rebuild and then deploy. The issue should be resolved.

Comment: I also deleted the .vs folder, not sure if it was needed.

Comment: I'll add it in for completeness. =)