# How to exclude Fody's PropertyChanged.dll from UWP package?

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp, fody-propertychanged

We are using Fody.PropertyChanged on our Xamarin project which works great but when we try to upload the package to the store it rejects it because it says:

> The debug configuration test detected the following errors:
>   The binary PropertyChanged.dll is built in debug mode.

According to this [link](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/46006468-failure-in-uwp-application-certification) the dll is not necessary on the package but still it is included there...

I also saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106714/uwp-exclude-dependency-dll-to-be-copied-included-into-package) which has no answer.

We are using PropertyChanged 2.1.1 
Our core project is a SharedProject and not a PCL so PropertyChanged must be imported in the UWP project but it shouldn't be included on the package for deploy.

Thanks!

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue in my side. Please show more detail about the version of `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: thank you @NicoZhu-MSFT for your time. I edited the question to add more detail. I will try to put together a dummy sample later.